# PHP: protecting "sensitive" values from being returned using ini_get and/or phpinfo()

Tags: php

Let's say that some setting in php.ini contains passwords which we don't want exposed (it's set using php_admin_value in php-fpm config), but contains passwords for connecting to some database service.

Obviously it's OK if the PHP runtime environment is able to read these values and use it, but for whatever reason we don't want to expose it to the PHP code itself.

There are two ways I'm aware of for retrieving this, both of which successfully gets access to the secret, the first is ini_get("sensitive_config_option"), and the other is by way of phpinfo(); (which outputs it visually so either need to use output buffering and parse, or read the screen, so more work than ini_get but still viable).

Does anyone know of a way to not expose such "sensitive" values to the code?

Specifically the value to be "protected" here is session.save_path.

Comment: Depending on your setup, you can use environment variables. These can come from different sources, e.g. Apache, Kubernetes, AWS services,...

Comment: You can use `disable_functions` to prevent all use of `ini_get` and `phpinfo`, but that will prevent other uses of those functions too. Why would `session.save_path` need to be secured against a user seeing it?

Comment: @GuidoFaecke I'm not sure what you mean, and environment variables are accessible to the PHP code too by way of $_SERVER if I recall correctly.

Comment: @MosheKatz Two words:  "untrusted clients".  session.save_path in this case contains passwords which ideally we'd like to not expose to clients.  disable_functions are interesting, and certainly would get the job done, however, there are legitimate uses for both of these functions so blocking them lightly is probably not wise.

Comment: What is your threat model? If by "untrusted clients" you mean "visitors to the web application through a browser", there is a much simpler solution: [check all user-provided input that might be used as a file name/path](https://www.php.net/manual/en/security.filesystem.php). If you mean "people who host their own code on my server", then you have a much bigger problem than just whether they can read the session storage files, and you need to take a very good look at multi-tenant server design (like cPanel and Plesk do it).

Comment: No.  I mean clients deploying vulnerable wordpress modules.  So yes, "people who host their own code on my server" (and cpanel and plesk have some glaring holes of their own which is considered best practices).  We continuously track and mitigate various issues, this is just being introduced now as we're looking to move sessions from file storage into redis (in part for performance reasons, and in part for load balancing).